# I want to add a link to php document that goes back to previous page

Tags: php

I am making an email me form using PHP and when you don't fill required fields you are sent to another page with errors that you need to correct.

At the bottom of these errors I want to make return link, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, because Dreamweaver shows me an error at the line I wrote. So here is the code and I will mark the line with comment.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "example@example.com";
$email_subject = "website html form submissions";

function died($error) {
    echo "Atsiprašome, bet yra klaidų Jūsų užpildytoje formoje.<br /><br /> ";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Grįžkite ir ištaisykite klaidas.<br /><br />";
    echo "<a href="contacts.html">Atgal</a>";  //this is the line
    die();
}



if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['last_name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['telephone']) || !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('Atsiprašome, bet yra klaidų Jūsų užpildytoje formoje.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];   // required
$email_from = $_POST['email'];      // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];   // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments'];     // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'Neteisingai įvestas el. paštas.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'Neteisingai įvestas vardas.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'Neteisingai įvesta pavardė.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'Neteisingai įvesta žinutė.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Ačiū už Jūsų žinutę.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: It says its syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<a href="contacts.html">Atgal</a>";  //this is the line
```

What you are doing here is ending the string literal at `<a href=`.

What you need to do is change it to:

```
echo "<a href='contacts.html'>Atgal</a>";
```

Comment: Yep! To PHP you've got two strings and some PHP code in the middle. That is why you were getting a syntax error. If you look at the colour change in the middle of the string, this should become obvious.

Comment: Thank you very much. Forgot about that :)

Comment: That's okay. When the time passes, please mark this answer as correct for future readers.

Comment: Oh, you need only 5 mins to wait :o

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, quotation marks are used to mark the start and end of a string. You can use either single or double quotes.

`'This is a string'`

`"This too!"`

As you can see, you can use either single or double quotes. However, we also expect quotes to appear *within* strings. So how do we deal with that?

Well, one option is to use Chris Cooney's answer and make sure that your quotes inside the string are different from those that mark the start and end:

`"I'm a string"`

`'"Murder," she wrote'`

Those are both valid.

But what about times when you need to use the *same* type of quotation inside your string that you opened it with? For instance, maybe you need both types in your string. In that case, you must *escape* the quotations. All that means is adding  `\` in front of them.

`'I\'m a valid string!'`

Based on this, you could fix your issue on this line:

```
echo "<a href="contacts.html">Atgal</a>";
```

by writing any of these:

```
echo "<a href='contacts.html'>Atgal</a>";

echo "<a href=\"contacts.html\">Atgal</a>";

echo '<a href=\'contacts.html\'>Atgal</a>';
```

just to name a few.

Comment: Thank you for these examples :)